# Count ways to reach Nth row

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given a N*M grid I need to reach last row with following operations :

```
If am at odd row number then i can move to only diagonal elements of next row
If am at even row number then i can move to diagonal elements or element below it.
```

Now i need to count ways to reach last row.

Example : If N=2 and M=5 then answer is 8.

8 ways are:

(1,1) to (2,2)

(1,2) to (2,1)

(1,2) to (2,3)

(1,3) to (2,2)

(1,3) to (2,4)

(1,4) to (2,3)

(1,4) to (2,5)

(1,5) to (2,4)

Now given N and M I need to count ways to reach Nth row

Comment: Is the move (1,4) to (2,4) supposed to be straight down? Or is it supposed to be (1,4) to (2,3)?

Comment: @Xoque55 Sorry it was typing mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1: Defining the Problem**

Let's start off with some notation that will hopefully keep things clear:

Let $r$ be the number of rows and $c$ be the number of columns in our grid. Let $(i,j)$ be the grid point in the $i$-th row and $j$-column of the grid. Your rules indicate that

> If I am at an odd row number, then I can move to only diagonal elements of next row.
>   If I am at an even row number, then I can move to diagonal elements or element below it.

In terms of our notation and we are at the point ($i,j$),

- **If $i$ is odd**, then our moves are only allowed to points diagonally $(i+1, j-1)$ or $(i+1,j+1)$. We need to be a little careful about what happens when our point is on the edge of the grid in either the first column or the last column. That is, when $j=1$ or $j=c$. If $j=1$, we can only move from $(i,1)$ diagonally to the right to the point $(i+1,2)$; similarly if $j=c$, we can only move from $(i,c)$ diagonally to the left to the point $(i+1,c-1)$.
- **If $i$ is even**, then we can do both of the moves for odd $i$ in addition to the point directly below $(i,j)$. So our moves are to either $(i+1,j-1), (i+1,j),$ or $(i+1,j+1)$. Following the same reason described above regarding the edge grid points we have limited moves for $j=1$ and $j=c$. If $j=1$, then our moves are to either $(i+1,1)$ or $(i+1,2)$. Similarly, if $j=c$, then our moves are to either $(i+1,c-1)$ or $(i+1,c)$.

Now define $f(r,c)$ as the number of ways to start from any upper grid point $(1,c)$ to the lower row $(r,c)$ by following the rules outlined above. I started working out a few cases by hand in attempt to generalize the formula for $f(r,c)$ for $r,c\geq 2$. You really can't do much if either $r$ or $c$ equals 1. However, it quickly became overwhelming to count the paths so I tried to think about the problem recursively.

---

**Part 2: An Example**

To model this problem recursively, it makes sense to keep track of the number of ways to get from a specific point on the top row to a specific point on the bottom row. Then, by adding another row of grid points to the bottom of the grid, we can do the following: Find the number of ways for each old bottom point to a new bottom point. Then, using the number of ways to get from a top row point to each old bottom row, we can multiply the top-to-old-bottom ways by each of the ways an old-bottom row point can reach a particular new-bottom row point. I realize this paragraph is exceptionally unclear so here's a worked example:

Example 1: Find $f(4,3)$ recursively.

So we're dealing with a grid of 4 rows and 3 columns. Let $A,B,C$ be the top 3 points of the grid and let the next row of points be labeled $D,E,F$. We'll worry about the other 6 unlabeled points later. So we have

\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & C\\
D & E & F\\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\end{bmatrix}

New notation: define $P_Q$ as the number of ways to go from point $P$ down to point $Q$. So in this example, $A_D$ is the number of ways form $A$ to $D$; $B_F$ is the number of ways to g from $B$ to $F$, etc..

Let's figure out how many ways we can get from a point in the top row to every point on the second row. Since the first row is odd-numbered, we can only move diagonally so we have:

- $A_D = 0 \quad A_E = 1 \quad A_F = 0$
- $B_D = 1 \quad B_E = 0 \quad B_F = 1$
- $C_D = 0 \quad C_E = 1 \quad C_F = 0$

Let's put the values in a matrix for convenience:
$$M_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1& 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
The way to interpret $M_1$ is: the $(m,n)$-th entry tell you how many ways you can go from the $m$-th top grid point down to the $n$-th bottom grid point. This idea will become very useful later. You'll also notice the symmetry involved here: $A$ and $C$ have essentially the same number of moves since they are just reflected over the center of the $4\times 3$ grid.

Anyway, let's now assign names to the third row of points, say, $G,H,I$:
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & C\\
D & E & F\\
G & H & I \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\end{bmatrix}

We are interested in finding the values for $A_G, A_H, A_I, B_G, \ldots, C_I$. 
Consider the values for $A_G, A_H, A_I$, the number of ways to reach $G,H,$ or $I$ can be reached from either $A$.

Using our notation, we can express these values simply:
$$A_G = A_D(D_G) + A_E(E_G) + A_F(F_G) \\
A_H = A_D(D_H) + A_E(E_H) + A_F(F_H) \\
A_I = A_D(D_I) + A_E(E_I) + A_F(F_I)$$

So it will be worth our time to find the values of $D_G, \ldots, F_I$. This time though, we need to remember that the second row has more options (diagonal and straight-down) so we have:

- $D_G = 1 \quad D_H = 1 \quad D_I = 0$
- $E_G = 1 \quad E_H = 1 \quad E_I = 1$
- $F_G = 0 \quad F_H = 1 \quad F_I = 1$

Again, like we did for $M_1$, let's interpret the above information as a matrix:
$$M_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

It is also worth noting that we can express all the nine ways $A_G, \cdots, C_I$ to get from the top row to the third row in the form of a product of matrices. If you have experience with the standard dot product and/or matrix multiplication, you can convince yourself that this formulation works with our notation. Explicitly, the total number of ways to get from the top row $A,B,C$ to the bottom row $G,H,I$ will be the sum of the entries in the matrix product $M_3$:

$$M_3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_G & A_H & A_I \\
B_G & B_H & B_I \\
C_G & C_H & C_I \\
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_D & A_E & A_F \\
B_D & B_E & B_F \\
C_D & C_E & C_F \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
D_G & D_H & D_I \\
E_G & E_H & E_I \\
F_G & F_H & F_I \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Now we can take advantage of defining $M_1$ and $M_2$ in the way we did:
$$ M_3 = M_1 M_2 
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1& 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Though we haven't considered the 4th (last) row to compute $f(4,3)$, we should interpret what $M_3$ is telling us. Again, just like $M_1$ and almost like $M_2$, the $(m,n)$ entry of $M_3$ will tell us the number of ways to go from the $m$-th top grid point ($A,B,C$) to the $n$-th grid point of the third row ($G,H,I$). With a little work, you can see that that each entry of $M_3$ can be verified by counting the paths from $A$ to $G$, $A$ to $H$, ..., $C$ to $I$. There will be 10 in all. But this is also the sum of all the entries of $M_3$ (!) so we can conclude that $f(3,3) = 10$.

This is where the recursive part begins to reveal itself. Let's fill out the last row of our $4\times 3$ grid with the points $J,K,L$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
G & H & I \\
J & K & L \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We can figure out $f(4,3)$ by realizing that the number of ways to get from the top row to the fourth row is just a matrix multiplication: the matrix representing the number of ways to go from the top row to the third row (which is the $M_3$ matrix) multiplied by a matrix representing the number of ways to go from the third row to the fourth row.

But the matrix going from the third row to the fourth row is in general the same as the matrix going from any odd-numbered row to the next row. We did this earlier when we created $M_1$ (!) So we can compute $f(4,3)$ by summing the entries in $M_4$:

$$M_4 = M_3 M_1 \\
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1& 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The sum of the entries in $M_4$ is $f(4,3) = 14$ which doesn't take too long to verify by hand.

---

**Part 3: Generalizing the Approach**

Now that we've worked through an example thoroughly, we can generalize the problem to find $f(r,c)$ for arbitrary natural numbers $r,c \geq 2$.

Step 1: Determine the "odd-row" matrix $M_1$. This means create a $c \times c$ matrix such that the $(m,n)$-th entry indicates the number of ways a the $m$-th grid point can reach the $n$-th grid point in a $2\times c$ grid. The only hiccups in the entries of the diagonal-only paths are the two endpoints but here are some examples:

$c=2: M_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$c=3: M_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$c=4: M_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$

From these cases we observe that $M_1$ is all zeros except for ones down the super- and sub-diagonals.

Step 2: Determine the "even-row" matrix $M_2$. This will also be a $c \times c$ matrix. Since we can move straight down from the even row, we should expect more entries than in $M_1$:

$c=2: M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$c=3: M_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

$c=4: M_1 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

So we observe that $M_2$ is just like $M_1$, but with ones down the diagonal also. So we can go so far to say that $M_2 = M_1 + I$ where $I$ is the $c \times c$ identity matrix.

Step 3: Determine how many $M_1$'s you need. Something not mentioned clearly in the worked example above is that $M_1$ is the "solution" for any problem where $r=2$. That is, if we define $s(X)$ as the sum of the entries of the matrix $X$, then $f(2,c) = s(M_1)$ for $c\geq 2$.

From the example we see that to increment the solution matrix incorporating an odd-numbered row we should the current matrix by $M_1$. If we incorporate an even-numberd row, we should instead multiply by the $M_2 = M_1 + I$. Explicitly, when $M_1$ and $M_2$ are defined as size $c \times c$, we have, in terms of powers of $M_1 M_2$ and $M_1$:

- $f(2,c) = s(M_1) = s([M_1 M_2]^0 M_1^1$
- $f(3,c) = s(M_1 M_2) = s([M_1 M_2]^1 M_1^0)$
- $f(4,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1) = s([M_1 M_2]^1 M_1^1)$
- $f(5,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1 M_2) = s([M_1 M_2]^2 M_1^0)$

Seeing that $[M_1 M_2]$ is so common, it is worth condensing it further. It can be verified that

$c=2: M_1 M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$c=3: M_1 M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$

$c=4: M_1 M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$

$c=5: M_1 M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

$c=6: M_1 M_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

In this way we can also characterize $K = M_1 M_2$ as a [pentadiagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadiagonal_matrix) with 2's on the main diagonal and with 1's on the diagonals above and below the main diagonal, in the upper left corner, and in the lower right corner.

We're nearly there; let's re-characterize the solution values in terms of the new powers of $K$:

- $f(2,c) = s(M_1) = s(K^0 M_1^1$
- $f(3,c) = s(M_1 M_2) = s(K^1 M_1^0)$
- $f(4,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1) = s(K^1 M_1^1)$
- $f(5,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1 M_2) = s(K^2 M_1^0)$
- $f(6,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1 M_2 M_1) = s(K^2 M_1^1)$
- $f(7,c) = s(M_1 M_2 M_1 M_2 M_1 M_2) = s(K^3 M_1^0)$

By continuing in this fashion, we can see that the "ultimate" expression for the solution is

$$f(r,c) = s(K^{(\lceil r/2 \rceil)-1} M_1^{1-(r \mod 2)})$$
where $r,c \geq 2$, $M_1$ is of size $c \times c$ and has only ones along its super- and sub-diagonals, $K = M_1(M_1+I)$ is the pentadiagonal matrix described above, and $r \mod 2$ takes on a value of 1 if $r$ is odd, 0 if $r$ is even.

**Part 4: Results**
Here is a table of some values of $f(r,c)$:

\begin{bmatrix}
r | c & | & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
-& - & -& -& -& -& -\\ 
2 & | & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
3 & | & 4 & 10 & 16 & 22 & 28 \\
4 & | & 4 & 14 & 26 & 38 & 50 \\
5 & | & 8 & 34 & 68 & 104 & 140 \\
6 & | & 8 & 48 & 120 & 180 & 286 \\
\end{bmatrix}